# Python pathing to find modules/classes to import

Tags: python, path

I am new to Python and I am looking to find out how Python discovers the path to modules it imports from.  This would be equivalent to `CLASSPATH` in Java and `PERL5LIB` in Perl.

E.g. the import block in a script I am looking at looks something like this:

```
import os
import resource

from localnamespace.localmodule import some_class
```

I understand that `os` and `resource` are native to Python (are part of the core language API) but still the interpreter must have some pointer where to find them.  As for `localnamespace.localmodule`, how do we tell the interpreter where to find this module because it the directory in which this script is does not have a subdirectory named `localnamespace`.

Comment: Look at the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` and `sys.path`.

Comment: I don't have `PYTHONPATH` set, yet the script finds the imports

Comment: Then the default path kicks in. Inspect `sys.path` to find out what it is.

Comment: Does the documentation for `import` help? http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import. This has a fairly detailed description of how import searches for modules

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**

In summary, the search process goes something like:

1) Previously imported in `sys.modules`?

2) If no, can I find it in the script / interpreter directory?

3) If no, can I find it in any of the directories in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?

4) If no, `ImportError`

**The Longer Answer**

Referring to the documentation an [`import`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) statement first looks at [`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules) which is a dictionary of currently or recently loaded modules.

It it can't find the module there it searches through [`sys.meta_path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path) - the actual paths here vary between implementations.  In general, import paths will be defined in [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path), which is a list of directories including those in the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`.

The documentation for `sys.path` describes itself as:

> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.
>
> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), path[0] is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first. Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries inserted as a result of PYTHONPATH.